# Books on layout and space sequencing in game design

Tags: 3d, level-design, books

I'm currently looking into level design books. So far I've read two, *The How's And Why's of Level Design* and *the Ultimate Level Design Guide*.

While both were useful they did not discuss layout and space sequencing as much as I was looking for. I'm looking for stuff like this:

[image]

I couldn't find books that pertain to this specific subject. Do you happen to know any?

Comment: seems like people are just voting up because pretty pictures. its not a good question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not support questions asking for resources.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "Pacing" for space sequencing.

I don't think that you're going to find much more than blogs by designers and the occasional post mortem with a design section.

Have you tried looking up syllabuses that include environment and level design to see what their reading list looks like?

However, 100% of the designers I know learned their patterns from tearing apart and studying existing games.  When someone asks "how do I become a designer" and all the answers come back "play games" they really mean "play games and dissect everything they do."

To summarize: play a lot of games, find if the designer/company has a development blog.

And check this out: [David Perry's Design Challenge](http://www.design3.com/industry-insight/david-perry/item/2542-the-%E2%80%98david-perry-challenge%E2%80%99-earn-a-personal-recommendation-letter-from-david-perry)